# iOS sharing instagram stories with Open App Link Or Deep Link option

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instagram

How to share Instagram stories with an Open app link or deep-link option on stories same as Spotify do? Click on that button "Play on Spotify" they will open the Spotify application with the particular song we shared. I've checked the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/) given by Facebook but I didn't find anything regarding this.

Is there any specific user account needed for this or do we need to send a request to Facebook separately?

[image]

Comment: You need to know the custom uri scheme to open the application, and what needs to be send in the deep link URL so that the target application can process it.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Not yet. If I found then I will post here.

Comment: @Chetankasundra You found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an app in the facebbok developer console. You can review this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/overview